# HDFS: where FSImage & edit log stored

Tags: hdfs, hadoop2

I have one question DOes FSImage & edit logs stored in some shared NFS for Hadoop 2.0 or both active & passive name node have copies of fsimage & edit log locally?

Answer (score 0):

The use of a shared NFS mount for storing HDFS NameNode edits is considered optional in modern deployments that use [HDFS High Availability Using the Quorum Journal Manager](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSHighAvailabilityWithQJM.html), because there are 3 JournalNodes storing redundant copies of the edits.  Some users still prefer to keep a copy of fsimage on NFS as an extra safety net.  Depending on the NFS infrastructure, it can be a throughput bottleneck during checkpoints.

Comment: Thanks for response. So if it's not NFS, does it store both fsimage &editlog locally on both active and passive node?

Comment: @user3459151 , both NameNodes (active and standby) will have copies of fsimage and edits.  All JournalNodes will have copies of edits (but not fsimage).